# SQL Server 2012 with Between 2 datetime2

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I got a problem with my query, SQL Server 2012 and vb 2015

Here the SQL logic and it's pretty simple: I just don't see the simpler way to do it...

Ex: I got 2 dates too make a period which should be static: 31-10-XXXX and 1-11-XXXX

I don't know how much year I got and I need all the periods to be put into a combobox.

Here is a sample of what I do: I'm a noob at SQL :)

Getting the first date and last date in the table

```
Declare @time1 datetime2, @time2 datetime2 

SET @time1 = (select top 1   DateCreated from table order by DateCreated asc) 
SET @time2 = (select   top 1 DateCreated from table order by DateCreated desc)
```

and make a loop through each period until i got no row with that select:

```
Loop
    Select * 
    from Table 
    where DateCreated between '2013-10-31' and '2014-11-01'

    Return X periode
    counter + 1 (which is year)
End
```

Can I make that easier or any advice? And if I could put that in just 1 call

I could make a couple of call to DB put i want too understand and im sure 
that's not the better or cleaner way!

Comment: your dates are `31-10-xxxx` in the tables? as actual date/time fields? or strings?

Comment: the date are 31-10-2014 ex the are datetime2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be on target, but... If you are trying to report on a Month period something like this may work for you:

```
        Acivity_Month   Sum
        2014.12 4170.49
        2015.01 7300.00
        2015.02 3255.00
        2015.03 3037.00
        2015.04 2155.00
        2015.05 3933.00
        2015.06 863.17
        2015.07 485.00
        2015.08 826.67
```

For arbitrary date ranges you could create a table to join with that has the date range and a 'name' to group on.

---

Sorry my SQL wasn't included in the post.

```
        SELECT CONVERT(char(7),datetime2,102) YYYY_MM, SUM(TotTransAmt) AS [Sum]
        FROM     MAF01
        WHERE  (LineItem = '1')
        GROUP BY CONVERT(char(7),datetime2,102)
```

You could use YEAR(datetime2) to group on.

Comment: no its for find the year (each period) i got in that table

Comment: Yea im gonna try that dunno if that works but you send me on the right line!